# Differing DPI [font sizes] in QWebView compared to all other QWidgets?

Tags: css, fonts, qt4, dpi, qwebview

I have a QWebView which displays some HTML content and I used CSS to style the text:

```
body { font-size: 10pt; }
```

The window with the QWebView also has a `QTextEdit` field, for which I have set the font like this:

```
QFont newFont;
newfont.setPointSize(10);
myEditField->setFont(newFont);
```

Unfortunately, the text displayed in the `QWebView` is slightly larger than the text displayed in the `QTextEdit`. I have a feeling that this has something to do with DPI settings being different in the `QWebView`.

[image]

Is there a way to get the same font sizes displayed for both the `QWebView` and the `QTextEdit`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explanation of this behavior has been given on [the bugreports](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-29571):

> It appears to be true that WebKit assumes 96 dpi as a fixed resolution. If this is how web content is designed then we have a problem changing that, because there are other people that expect WebKit to render web content like in web browsers.
>   See also https://www.webkit.org/blog/57/css-units/

They suggested two solutions:

> QWebView provides [setZoomFactor](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebview.html#zoomFactor-prop) and [setTextMultiplier](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebview.html#setTextSizeMultiplier) which I believe could be used to get the desired behaviour (matching the QWidget ).

You can calculate zoom factor and text multiplier using current DPI:

```
QWidget* window = QApplication::desktop()->screen();
const int horizontalDpi = window->logicalDpiX(); 
m_view->setZoomFactor(horizontalDpi / 96.0);
```

Using `QWebSettings::ZoomTextOnly` you can apply zooming to the text only.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little tricky. I found a good way to get accurate DPI measurements is from QApplication, example:

```
QWidget* window = QApplication::desktop()->screen();
int horizontalDpi = window->logicalDpiX();
```

As far as font goes, you can use `QWidget::fontMetrics()` to get a good font metrics information.

I think a combination of both will give you some consistency between your web view and text edit.

Good luck.